# Changing zoom in D3.js from mousewheel to control+mousewheel

Tags: javascript, user-interface, d3.js, zooming

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13713528/how-to-disable-pan-for-d3-behavior-zoom) I know how to disable mousewheel zoom in D3.js. How can I remap it to holding control button down plus mousewheel? Thanks.

Comment: You would need to modify the D3 source to get access to the relevant event handlers. See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/src/behavior/zoom.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution that does not need to modify the D3.js source.

I based my solution on this question: [How to temporarily disable the zooming in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18788188/how-to-temporarily-disable-the-zooming-in-d3-js)

Instead of clicking on a button to enable/disable zooming, I used keydown/keyup events:

```
svg.call(zoom = d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redrawOnZoom)).on('dblclick.zoom', null);

var zooming = false;

function redrawOnZoom() {
  if (zooming) {
    svgContainer.attr('transform', 'translate(' + zoom.translate() + ')' + ' scale(' + zoom.scale() + ')');
  }
};

d3.select("body").on("keydown", function () {
    zooming = d3.event.ctrlKey;
});

d3.select("body").on("keyup", function () {
     zooming = false;
});
```

Here is a complete fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tabacof/dcbor8eL/3/

Comment: but the scale value still changes when you scroll, but not do zooming.

Answer (score 6):

Add a filter function to the zoom handler (https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoom_filter).

In `d3.event` the element `ctrlKey` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/ctrlKey) indicates if the control key was pressed or not.

Returning `false` in the filter function ignores the event.

```
zoom.filter(function () {
    return d3.event.ctrlKey;
});
```

Comment: works somewhat. now, when i hold ctrl to zoom, it is very sensitive (zooms too much)

Comment: You have to adjust the wheelData. There was added a 10-times offset if ctrlKey is pressed.

https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/issues/204
https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom/commit/4d2a5f15eb2bd86025984a4f90085259dfe59941